# If list returns empty display message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, count

Using MVC I am passing a `Projects` list to the view.

```
@if (Model.Projects != null && Model.Projects.Count > 0)
{
<fieldset>
    <table class="items" summary="@T("This is a table of the delivery Runs in your application")">
        <colgroup>
}

else
{
//no data available
}
```

Model.Projects.Count > 0 is saying:

> operator > cant be applied to operands of type 'method group' and
>   'int'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

`Model.Projects.Count() > 0`

or

```
Model.Projects.Any()
```

if you are using resharper, it will recommend you for Model.Projects.Any()

Comment: You should definitely use `Any()` instead of `Count()` since you're only interested in whether there *are* any projects. Counting the items in a potentially large collection is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Count is a method. Your code must be

```
Model.Projects.Count()
```

Comment: Or better yet, `Model.Projects.Any()`

Answer (score 3):

You are treating `Count` as if it were a property.

It's a method. You need to call `Count()`. E.g.

```
@if (Model.Projects != null && Model.Projects.Count() > 0)
{
<fieldset>
    <table class="items" summary="@T("This is a table of the delivery Runs in your    application")">
        <colgroup>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the brackets after Count. `Count()` is a method not a property, so your code should be:

```
@if (Model.Projects != null && Model.Projects.Count() > 0)
{
    <fieldset>
        <table class="items" summary="@T("This is a table of the delivery Runs in your application")">
        <colgroup>
}
```

but seeing as you are only concerned with whether there are any elements in `Model.Projects`, not how many there are, instead of

```
Model.Projects.Count() > 0
```

you could use

```
Model.Projects.Any()
```